# Where can I upload a document in RSA Archer that is available to all users?

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

Our use case is to upload a document into Archer that would be accessible to all Archer users who has a general user role.

We have had a couple of ideas, like a SharePoint site, may be an attachment field on a contacts records...but, we don't have a SharePoint site setup and cant import attachments into millions of contact records.

Comment: Is this for all of Archer or for specific app(s)?

Comment: It is for all of Archer@DjP

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Archer on-prem you can upload the file to the company_files \ [pin] and in the Contacts create as text box layout object and create a hyperlink to that file.

If hosted reach out to Archer support.

Comment: we dont have a SharePoint site setup -DjP

Comment: @crazyrobert I've updated my answer above.

Comment: @crazyrobert you can't upload the file to \company_files\[pin]\?